# Login form placed in default home page

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay portal 6.1.1CE.

I have selected zoe-resort as my portal theme.

By default the login form shows only when we click in the signin link.

I wants the form in the home page by default.

How can i include the login form in the portal-normal.vm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By placing the login form on the theme, it will persist through out all of your sites pages!

If you would like to just add it to your Home page, then I would highly recommend using the Login portlet and drop it on the portlet.

To do so:

1. Login as an administrator.
2. In the Dockbar, click on the "Add" drop down menu, click "More..."
3. Find the "Sign In" portlet by using search.
4. Drag the portlet to where you'd like it to show.

Comment: thanks..you are telling the exact way. but actually this theme is used for my portal home page only,after login it will redirected to a site having another theme.thats why am trying to doing this..

Comment: @user1682724 regardless of what you're doing, the steps are still valid. I wouldn't modify the theme to include the portlet.